# How can I specify formats for ActiveAdmin file picker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have my ActiveAdmin form:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :orders_file, as: :file
    end
    actions
  end
```

And I want to specify the file picker to only search for .xls, .xlsx files but I can't seem to find how.

Also, how can I make the file required in a way that it doesn't hit the controller if a file is not selected?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use accept attribute of HTML

```
f.input :orders_file, as: :file, required: true, input_html: {accept: ".xls, .xlsx"}
```

you can also check if the file extension is xls or not in controller action like this

```
if !params[:file].path.split('.').last.to_s.casecmp?('xls')
  flash[:error] = 'Please upload valid xls file'
  redirect_back fallback_location: { action: 'index' }
else
  # write your code 
end
```

Comment: It worked. just a small question, do you know how to make the file required in a way that it doesn't hit the controller if a file is not selected? I want it to be compulsory. The file shouldn't be blank. But I can't do it as validation in the model since the file is not an attribute in the model.

Comment: That's great, but I was kinda hoping the error was shown under the upload field like normal validations, but I guess that works too. Thank you!

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon the best way to say thank you is upvote the answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought by marking as selected answer it was upvoted. Done :D

Comment: ahhaa.. no problm :) keep smile :)